# node 'fs' and 'request' to upload file via REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I am trying to use a REST API to upload a file. I have a function that works for every other type of request, but this one (which uploads a file) doesn't want to work:

```
var createItem = function ()
{
    request.post(
        {
            url:browser.params.baseRestUrl + 'repositories/Samples/items',
            auth: browser.params.auth,
            body: fs.createReadStream(filepath),
            form:
                {
                    headers: {'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
                              'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="oneHourSally3.fmw"',
                              'Accept': 'application/json'
                             },
                }
        },
        function(e,r,user){ console.log("Status code of createItem('oneHourSally'): " + r.statusCode);});
};
```

This returns a http 415 (unsupported media type) error.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that error implies that the server is only willing to accept a specific `Content-Type`. You're specifying `application/octet-stream` and the server tells you it doesn't accept that. Consult the documentation of the API to figure out what is supported, or contact the authors of the API via a support channel.